# Count Rows before Group By

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I want to count the number of articles (expected: `2`) after grouping by an id but it currently returns only rows with `1` since it counts the occurrences after the GROUP BY.

```
    article:
    +-------+---------+
    |  id   |  name   |
    +-------+---------+
    |   1   |  Apple  |
    |   2   |  Orange | 
    |   3   |  Peaches| 
    +-------+---------+


    article_category:
    +---------------+----------------+
    |  article_id   |  category_id   |
    +---------------+----------------+
    |       1       |        1       |
    |       1       |        2       |
    |       1       |        3       |
    |       2       |        1       |
    +---------------+----------------+
```

Can this be done without a subquery and without using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`? (I'm pretty restricted as I'm using an API endpoint). My only other idea is to simply retrieve all ids and then count them with PHP.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) as number_articles
FROM article a
INNER JOIN article_category c ON a.id = c.article_id
WHERE c.category_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Desired output:

```
    +--------------------+
    |  number_articles   | 
    +--------------------+
    |          2         |
    +--------------------+
```

Here is an SQLFiddle as suggested in the comments: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b2975/1

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Btw, this is an inner join

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I created an SQLFiddle and adapted the query.

Comment: @Elektropepi, what is your expected result?

Comment: Can you do that in that way? As you said subquerying: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM
(SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM article a
INNER JOIN article_category c ON a.id = c.article_id
WHERE c.category_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY a.id)x;

Comment: No the problem is that I explicitly can't use subqueries.

Comment: @Elektropepi , check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the expected result you added now. You can remove the GroupBy, its really not achieving much here, this should work:

```
select count(distinct a.id)
from article a
INNER JOIN article_category c ON a.id = c.article_id
WHERE c.category_id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my question: I need to retrieve the number of articles `2` which isn't possible with this query either: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b2975/14

Comment: Can you please just post a little table of the expect output as you did for the table contents, this should be solveable really quickly if you do that.

Answer (score 1):

try below solution.

```
select count(DISTINCT a.id) as total
from article a
INNER join article_category c on a.id = c.article_id 
WHERE category_id in (1,2,3);
```

> RESULT:

```
total
2
```

Comment: If you change `LEFT` to `INNER JOIN` this works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just count the value of **c.category_id** instead of **a.id**

```
SELECT COUNT(c.category_id) FROM article a INNER JOIN 
article_category c ON a.id = c.article_id WHERE c.category_id 
IN (1, 2, 3) GROUP BY a.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.id)

FROM article a

INNER JOIN article_category c ON a.id = c.article_id
```